# Create a public controller method

Tags: custom-component, joomla-4.x

I have a controller method that outputs some JSON which should be publicly accessible

`index.php?option=com_mycomponent&task=mycontroller.json&format=json`

If I set this as a System > URL menu type set to guest or public it still redirects to the login page

How can I call a controller method publicly? Do I need to register it as a route or something like that?